# How can I cancel the deferred transaction in EOS after we push the deferred transaction in the blockchain

Tags: cleos, deferred-transactions

I have a action which execute the deferred transaction .  Let  I send the delay of 20 days . If I want to cancel the deferred transaction before 20 days . Is there any way I can do this ?

This is my action which I push to deferred the transaction .

```
void second::send(account_name from , account_name to ,asset  quantity,string  memo,uint64_t delay) {
            eosio::transaction t{};

            t.actions.emplace_back(
        eosio::permission_level(from, N(active)),       
        N(eosio.token),
        N(transfer),
                std::make_tuple(from,to,quantity,memo)
            );
            t.delay_sec = delay;
            t.send(N(memo), from);
        }

transfer( account_name from,
                      account_name to,
                      asset        quantity,
                      string      memo  ){....}
```

transfer is my action that execute the transaction .

Comment: How can we use the function   defined in   apply_context.hpp file  to cancel a deffered transaction                                                                                               bool apply_context::cancel_deferred_transaction( const uint128_t& sender_id, account_name sender ) {....}

Comment: The absolute path of function  'cancel_deferred_transaction ()' is    **/eos/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/apply_context.hpp**

Comment: You can import eosio library in your file to use it.

Comment: Yes I found the library but what is context here , the parameter that I have to pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void send(const uint128_t& sender_id, account_name payer, bool replace_existing = false)
```

First parameter(`sender_id`) is the id of the deferred transaction.
You can call `cancel_deferred(sender_id)` to cancel it.

See example in `delegate_bandwidth` on [GitHub](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/v1.1.4/contracts/eosio.system/delegate_bandwidth.cpp#L348).

Comment: Rocky  I have to make a new action  in my contract that implement the method **cancel_deferred(sender_id)** and import transaction.h in my header file ?

Comment: yes, need a new action.

Comment: hello could I update the deferred transaction